# Keep getting sendID mismatch with Firebase messaging class

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing the Messaging class that is modified from the [Firebase Java Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java). But it keep telling me `SenderId mismatch` error which I'm sure my app got the valid push token under the same firebase project. So I want to debug it for the reason why it can't send the push successfully. I tried to print the acccess token after it loaded my credential file but it prints null. Can anyone tell me what else that I can do to resolve this issue?

```
public class Messaging {

    private static final String MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { MESSAGING_SCOPE };

    private static final String TITLE = "FCM Test";
    private static final String BODY = "Test Body";
    private static final String DEVICE_TOKEN = "91bHb1hw6nhVs0JjjGAqBS1GQmNC....";
    /**
     * Sends request message to FCM using HTTP.
     *
     * @param message The message of the send request.
     * @throws FirebaseMessagingException
     */
    private static HashMap<String, String> sendMessage(final Message message) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        HashMap<String, String> respSet = new HashMap<String, String>();
        FirebaseMessaging fmInst = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();

        try {           
            String response = fmInst.send(message);
            Log4j.log.debug("Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response: " + response);

            respSet.put("returnMsg", response);
            respSet.put("returnCode", ReturnCode.Success);

        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            Log4j.log.debug("Unable to send message to Firebase, error code: " + e.getMessagingErrorCode());

            System.out.println("Push failed: " + e.getMessage());

            respSet.put("returnMsg", e.getMessage());
            respSet.put("returnCode", ReturnCode.PushFail);
        }
        return respSet;
    }

    /**
     * Sends notification message to FCM for delivery to registered devices.
     *
     * @throws FirebaseMessagingException
     */
    public static HashMap<String, String> sendCommonMessage(final String token, final String title, final String body,
            final String data) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        Message notificationMessage = buildNotificationMessage(token, title, body, data).build();
        Log4j.log.debug("FCM Msg body: " + new Gson().toJson(notificationMessage));
        Log4j.log.trace("FCM request body for message using common notification object:");
        return sendMessage(notificationMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the body of a notification message request.
     *
     * @return the builder object of the notification message.
     */
    private static Message.Builder buildNotificationMessage(final String token, final String title, final String body,
            final String data) {
        Notification notification = Notification.builder().setTitle(title).setBody(body).build();

        Message.Builder message = Message.builder().putData("body", data).setToken(token).setNotification(notification);

        return message;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the enviroment with Firebase default credentials.
     */
    public static void initializeWithDefaultCredentials(final String credFilePath) throws IOException {
        // [START initialize_sdk_with_application_default]
        GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credFilePath))
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));

        Log4j.log.debug("Loaded credential: " + googleCredentials.toString());

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(googleCredentials).build();
        
        Log4j.log.debug("Access token: " + googleCredentials.getAccessToken());

        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }
        // [END initialize_sdk_with_application_default]
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> sendMsg(final String credFilePath, final String token, final String title,
            final String body, final String data) throws IOException, FirebaseMessagingException {
        initializeWithDefaultCredentials(credFilePath);
        return sendCommonMessage(token, title, body, data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FirebaseMessagingException {
        initializeWithDefaultCredentials("\\Cred_File.json");
        sendCommonMessage(DEVICE_TOKEN, TITLE, BODY, "Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hello. I'm expecting it could send the push message to my mobile device without problem. But the situation that I seem is somehow it keep telling me `SenderId mismatch` even I'm sure that credential file and app key are coming from the same firebase project(My app developer say so). So I want to figure out why is this happening.